# Could not restore a database

Tags: sql-server, backup

I do not understand this error message:

> There is insufficient free space on disk volume 'S:\' to create the database. The database requires 291.447.111.680 additional free bytes, while only 74.729.152.512 bytes are available.

It is true I have 74GB free on my disk S, but I'm trying to restore a backup file having only 2.4 GB.

Is it possible a backup of 2GB to fill 291 GB?

**Later edit**: Source database before backup has 52GB (data) + 225G (log).

Comment: Have you checked how much free space was there in the source DB before backup?

Comment: @Raj Source database before backup has 52GB (data) + 225GB (log).

Comment: @marc_s: Can I restore the database without the log file?

Comment: See [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413780/restore-sql-server-db-without-transaction-log) and its answer - basically: no, you cannot restore just the data files but skip the transaction log ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = N'C:\Path\YourBackup.bak'** to check the space used by the DB in the backup upon restoration. Basically, this will allow you to see how big it'll be, without actually restoring the backup.

Comment: Thanks. Can I restore the database without the log file?

Comment: Far as I know, no you can't. You can however try to circumvent this by restoring the log to a different drive for instance, as long as you give the necessary permissions to the drive / folder (NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER or NT SERVICE\MSSQL$InstanceName for a named instance, as per MSDN). After that you can shrink the log to a manageable size and move it back to where you need it. By far the easier option would be to shrink this on the source and take a new backup, then restore that. But of course, depending on the source, it may not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore the database on a separate drive. Let's say you are getting you don't have sufficient space on C: drive, then you can do it on another drive like D:\ , E:\ or anyone. You can do it like the below image

[image]